# Dropping rows based on specific values through python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataset that I am attempting to use:

https://storage.googleapis.com/hewwo/NCHS_-_Leading_Causes_of_Death__United_States.csv

I am wondering how I can specifically drop rows that contain certain values.  In this example, many rows from the "Cause Name" column have values of "All causes".  I want to drop any row that has this value for that column.  This is what I have tried so far:

```
death2[death2['cause_name' ]!= 'All Causes']
```

While this did not give me any errors, it also did not seem to do anything to my dataset.  Rows with "All causes" were still present.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No changes were made to your `DataFrame`. You need to reassign it if you want to change it.

```
death2 = death2[death2['cause_name' ]!= 'All Causes']
```

Comment: Thanks, simple dumb mistake that I never noticed. Worked with your help.